# Are there climatic projections for past conditions in Northern Europe?

Tags: climate-change, climate, history

I'm looking for projections of past climatic conditions during the last two millennia for northern Europe. I know there are initiatives studying tree rings, but I want to know whether there are interpolated surfaces or, at least, many localities studied in deep. Any suggestion?

Comment: https://bjerknes.uib.no/en and here https://nsidc.org/ you might want to look in the sources to find what you are looking for.

Comment: There is a huge amount of data. Can you please write where you have already searched and what you want to know more specifically? It is hard to answer such a general question.

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen, IDEALLY, I'm looking for bioclimatic datasets such as those provided by http://www.paleoclim.org/, but for the last two millennia. Alternatively, any database of predicted precipitation and temperatures would be of great help